# Attracted an "always downvoter"

Tags: support, questions, downvotes, downvote-reason

I think I've attracted someone who always downvotes all of my questions, often just minutes after I post them. I think because of the almost initial/instant -1 on my question, I might get fewer answers or attract fewer interested users to my question.

How should I deal with this issue? Is there a way to do something against this person?

I even have ideas of who could be that down voter / hater, but of course nothing but ideas and no proof. There is never any comment explaining the downvote.

**EDIT#1:**

I posted some questions recently mostly with the tag `Python`. Other than that there are other tags I used, but they're usually different from post to post.

**EDIT#2:**

I ask everyone to stay polite while answering my question. Not bad tone is required to inform me about stuff. This is a valid question for Meta. Please respect it as such.

Comment: What tag are you posting in? If its low traffic, and your question low quality, it could just be people lurking in the tag that look at every question.

Comment: I think you're confused. As of right now, you've posted 39 questions, only two of which are showing a negative (-1) score. How does that indicate that someone is always downvoting all of your questions? You should have a downvote on every single one of your questions in that case.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Post updated answering your question.

Comment: @KenWhite: Do you see when those votes happened? I've observed this behavior on at least 5 occasions and I think many of my question only afterwards got some positive votes, so that ofc now they're positive. Also it's quite strange that the downvotes appear only minutes after I created a question and without reason, almost as if someone checks my profile and looks for new questions to down vote.

Comment: Hmmm... Could it just be that your questions might not be that good, and people are just honestly downvoting them? Votes (and closures, and answers, and everything else) typically happen pretty fast at SO; people who monitor activity in tags usually are on top of new activity in those tags. (One of the tags I frequent typically has an answer or comment from a certain high-rep user that happens within a minute or two, no matter what time of day or night. I asked him in chat once if he ever slept, and he said *very little*.)

Comment: Also, something to note: There's no way for anyone to know when you personally post, unless they're invested enough in you to frequently visit your personal profile. It's pretty unlikely that someone would go to that trouble to track you to downvote your questions to cost you a whopping couple of rep points, don't you think?

Comment: @KenWhite: I think my questions tend to be difficult to answer, since I search the web a lot before putting them on SO plus I search SO naturally. I always try to put in as much information as I see anyhow related to solcing the question. If someone asks me for more information on something, I usually provide that too. So I don't think my questions are that bad. Maybe you can point me at something about my question, which is bad style?

Comment: @Zelphir you last post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641469/python-pytest-fails-remove-item-from-list-item-is-not-removed) is essentially *looks like* wall of code. Anyone looking at the python tag could have voted it down - and python is quite well populated tag... Also lack of MVCE cause vote to close, some people would just downvote the post (and it usually will happen as soon as post shows up - I usually downvote posts in my tags in first 1-3 minutes before they disappear from front page).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Can you make that an answer? I'll try improving next time with a MVCE (Minimal Working Example?). Didn't know that alone was already reason for downvotes. Yes my question contains a lot of code, but I think that's what I have to give, because it plays into the test code : / Should I rather link that code or post a link to my github repo for the whole project?

Comment: Looking at the question @AlexeiLevenkov linked, I'd agree with his assessment. You should probably learn what MCVE means (hint: the *M* means *Minimal*, and what you've posted looks far from *minimal* to me). It's probable that someone just saw the miniscule amount of text combined with the large amount of code and downvoted.

Comment: With regard to your question: Yes, something will be done automatically by the system if someone is serially downvoting you. If you have evidence that someone is doing so and the downvoting isn't automatically undone in a day or two, contact the team at the link on the bottom of the page. However, the two questions you've actually received downvotes on show no evidence of serial DVs (and in fact show evidence to the contrary), so in this case there doesn't appear to be anything that needs to be done. It appears you've written questions that users consider legitimately worthy of DVs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd be very surprised if you are targeted personally.

Why do you receive downvote "just minutes after I post": downvotes frequently will happen as soon as post shows up - there are plenty of people watching they favorite tags for good questions - and as result assessing them in first minutes. I.e. I usually downvote posts in my favorite tags in first 1-3 minutes before they disappear from front page. There are also several review queues targeting new questions that increase such exposure (your posts probably would not show up there due to your reputation) and hence putting even more eyes on just asked questions.

I.e. your last post (stackoverflow.com/questions/32641469/…) is essentially *looks like* wall of code. Anyone looking at the python tag could have voted it down - and python is quite well populated tag... Also lack of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) cause vote to close, some people would just downvote the post instead.

Note that there are many signs of "clearly not minimal sample" - like structures with multiple fields where 1-2 would likely be enough, a lot of trivial comments or arbitrary commented out code, just flat out vertical scroll on the code.

Answer (score 11):

Of your last 10 questions, only 2 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641469/python-pytest-fails-remove-item-from-list-item-is-not-removed and [Python decorators - Where do parameters come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468078/python-decorators-where-do-parameters-come-from)) have attracted downvotes. They were 10 days apart, and you had questions in between that were not downvoted. It's ridiculous to assume based upon this evidence alone that you are being specifically targeted by an individual. How would this even work? Do you think that somebody has been refreshing your profile for 10 days straight waiting for you to post a question for them to downvote, but somehow missed 2 questions in the process?

Two of your questions got downvoted because people thought they deserved downvotes. You are not being targeted. Get on with your life.

Comment: Seriously? As I've said, that's the impression I got. And your tone … was that needed? Especially that "Get on with your life" was pretty much unnecessary, don't you think? Let me be worried about what I want to be worried about, it's not your problem right?

Comment: @Zelphir In general, people tend to overreact to downvotes. It gets a bit tiresome hearing people complain about it all the time on Meta. Likely explains the tone of this answer.

Comment: In fairness to the OP [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583863/why-use-an-ampersand-character-in-pyqt-strings-for-gui-elements) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918073/tkinter-how-to-set-font-for-text) [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178031/jquery-multi-level-accordion-menu) (+3 more) that have a positive overall, but still have a downvote. Still seems like a lot of concern for imaginary internet points.

Comment: @Zelphir not to take anyone's side, but do be aware some people DO come to meta for 2-3 downvotes and FIGHT tooth and nail against it... more or less daily, so yeah people do end up having a short fuse about things like that. But yeah, I don't see Mark's answer as insulting. Curt, a bit to the point, sure... but impolite? Unnecessary? not really. His tip could be summarized with "you got some downvotes and lost a bit of imaginary internet points from it, get over it" is pretty much on par, even if delivery could be better

Comment: @theB yeah, I only looked at the first 10 posts. But note that the ones you've linked to are all over a month old - some of them by a long way. They're still not consistent with a serial downvoter targeting the OP.

Comment: @MarkAmery - Just to clarify: I'm not disagreeing with your assessment. It's difficult to see _any_ pattern in the downvoting, much less a concerted effort.  I was just looking for some justification for why someone _might_ feel like people are out to get them. Rational or not. (You still have my +1.)